# Check if a record has related records through Ransack. Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

Given two models. In my case `Course` that has many `Question`.

I want to know if it's possible, through Ransack, to query only the courses that has questions related.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was pretty simple: `questions_id_null: false`